# Gradle build failed - Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to open an old project to the android studio, getting this Gradle error

```
Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the gradle error states:

> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Follow the following steps:

- Close Android Studio and kill all the processes of Android Studio for

  - Mac => press Command + Option + Esc then force stop the process of Android Studio
  - Windows => Ctrl + Alt + Del keyboard shortcut and click on Task Manager then click More Details button to show All the running processes.
- Run Android Studio again
- Make sure you have active and working internet connection and try to build your project again

Comment: Killing the process sounds pretty unnecessary. You should try to clean build instead.

Comment: @Qunata might be possible but its recommended by gradle error so it would be better to give it a try